# How to reset glusterd configuration?

Tags: glusterfs

Somehow I can not get glusterfs running again on ubuntu 14.04. I used to have it up and running a few days ago, including a configured volume. Then I removed the start script from autostart.

Now I get "failed" on starting the daemon. Then I purged the package and tried to reinstall. This is where I get following output:

```
Setting up glusterfs-server (3.7.3-ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
 * Starting glusterd service glusterd                                                                                                                                    [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript glusterfs-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package glusterfs-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
                                                                                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
 glusterfs-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This are the entries of the logfile:

```
[2015-08-23 19:10:33.979995] I [MSGID: 106478] [glusterd.c:1346:init] 0-management: Maximum allowed open file descriptors set to 65536
[2015-08-23 19:10:33.980021] I [MSGID: 106479] [glusterd.c:1395:init] 0-management: Using /var/lib/glusterd as working directory
[2015-08-23 19:10:33.982396] W [MSGID: 103071] [rdma.c:4590:__gf_rdma_ctx_create] 0-rpc-transport/rdma: rdma_cm event channel creation failed [No such device]
[2015-08-23 19:10:33.982416] W [MSGID: 103055] [rdma.c:4896:init] 0-rdma.management: Failed to initialize IB Device
[2015-08-23 19:10:33.982427] W [rpc-transport.c:359:rpc_transport_load] 0-rpc-transport: 'rdma' initialization failed
[2015-08-23 19:10:33.982457] W [rpcsvc.c:1597:rpcsvc_transport_create] 0-rpc-service: cannot create listener, initing the transport failed
[2015-08-23 19:10:33.982464] E [MSGID: 106243] [glusterd.c:1619:init] 0-management: creation of 1 listeners failed, continuing with succeeded transport
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.272379] I [MSGID: 106513] [glusterd-store.c:2036:glusterd_restore_op_version] 0-glusterd: retrieved op-version: 30703
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.427785] I [MSGID: 106498] [glusterd-handler.c:3570:glusterd_friend_add_from_peerinfo] 0-management: connect returned 0
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.427848] I [rpc-clnt.c:972:rpc_clnt_connection_init] 0-management: setting frame-timeout to 600
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.508741] E [MSGID: 101075] [common-utils.c:314:gf_resolve_ip6] 0-resolver: getaddrinfo failed (Name or service not known)
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.508788] E [name.c:247:af_inet_client_get_remote_sockaddr] 0-management: DNS resolution failed on host gluster2
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.508957] I [MSGID: 106004] [glusterd-handler.c:5051:__glusterd_peer_rpc_notify] 0-management: Peer <gluster2> (<6184be8c-f171-455f-a94f-dcf3ac6e1be1>), in state <Peer in Cluster>, has disconnected from glusterd.
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.508993] E [MSGID: 106155] [glusterd-utils.c:199:glusterd_unlock] 0-management: Cluster lock not held!
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.514145] E [MSGID: 106408] [glusterd-peer-utils.c:120:glusterd_peerinfo_find_by_hostname] 0-management: error in getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
 [Unknown error -2]
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.519159] E [MSGID: 101075] [common-utils.c:3139:gf_is_local_addr] 0-management: error in getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

[2015-08-23 19:10:35.519192] E [MSGID: 106187] [glusterd-store.c:4243:glusterd_resolve_all_bricks] 0-glusterd: resolve brick failed in restore
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.519271] E [MSGID: 101019] [xlator.c:428:xlator_init] 0-management: Initialization of volume 'management' failed, review your volfile again
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.519280] E [graph.c:322:glusterfs_graph_init] 0-management: initializing translator failed
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.519285] E [graph.c:661:glusterfs_graph_activate] 0-graph: init failed
[2015-08-23 19:10:35.519655] W [glusterfsd.c:1219:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterd(glusterfs_volumes_init+0xcd) [0x7f8a6c1f507d] -->/usr/sbin/glusterd(glusterfs_process_volfp+0x126) [0x7f8a6c1f4f56] -->/usr/sbin/glusterd(cleanup_and_exit+0x69) [0x7f8a6c1f4589] ) 0-: received signum (0), shutting down
```

I believe I need to reset the configuration as the paths are now different. How do I do this?

Answer (score 13):

just found the solution. For reference:

After removing /var/lib/glusterd I was able to start glusterd.

Comment: Thanks, that's solved it all. However, would you give a hint how did you reach out to this solution?